# Why Storybook's array knob isn't updating when changing the content on it?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

When I see it in console, it does changes the array, but doesn't rerenders it. All other knobs work. I'm using a conditional to check if the `body`has `length` enough to render it.

Story:

```
import React from 'react'
import moment from 'moment'
import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react'
import {
  text,
  boolean,
  select,
  number,
  array,
  date,
  color as colorKnob
} from '@storybook/addon-knobs'
import Article from '@psl/ui/Article'
import ArticleReadMe from '@psl/ui/Article/README.md'

const defaultDate = new Date()

function formattedDateKnob(name, defaultValue) {
  const stringTimestamp = date(name, defaultValue)
  const currentDate = moment(stringTimestamp).format('dddd Do MMMM, YYYY')
  return currentDate
}
const defaultBody = ['First paragraph', 'Second paragraph']

const articleStories = storiesOf('Articles', module)
articleStories
  .addParameters({
    readme: {
      sidebar: ArticleReadMe
    }
  })
  .add('Article', () => {
    const isFetching = boolean('Is fetching?', false)
    const title = text('Title of the article', 'Obesity in premature babies')
    const articleDate = formattedDateKnob('Date', defaultDate)
    const articleBody = array('Body of article', defaultBody)
    const referenceLink = text('Reference link', 'https://link.com')
    const reference = text(
      'Reference',
      'https://meetinglibrary.asco.org/record/185967/abstract'
    )
    const source = text('Source', 'University of Washington School of Medicine')

    console.info(articleBody)
    return (
      <Article
        isFetching={isFetching}
        title={title}
        date={articleDate}
        body={defaultBody}
        referenceLink={referenceLink}
        reference={reference}
        source={source}
      />
    )
  })
```

Part of the component that renders that array:

```
  {body.length &&
    body.map((paragraph, index) => {
      return (
        <Typography type="body1" key={index} className={styles.body}>
          <Markup html={paragraph} />
        </Typography>
      )
    })}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should this

```
body={defaultBody}
```

be this?

```
body={articleBody}
```